# Gradle subprojects: how do I execute `check` only on main project?

Tags: gradle

I added a subproject to my gradle project and now whenever I execute the target `check`, it also runs the tests on my subproject.

I was hoping that I could run the `check`-task on the main project by specifying it as absolute task as

```
gradle :check
```

or

```
gradle ::check
```

but both commandlines still execute all tests.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the task-graph of a subproject from the main projects `build.gradle' and disable tasks.

This way you can disable the task when you call it on the main project, but it will still be enabled when you call the build file of the subproject directly:

```
project('subproject') {
    //disable 'check' and 'test' task
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        tasks.find {it.name=="check"}.enabled=false
        tasks.find {it.name=="test"}.enabled=false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this, so you would need to restructure your build (I think `check` task of the parent is by definition a aggregate of the sub-projects). You can have sub-projects depending on each other, I assume that might be what you want to model in your build.

Let's assume you have the sub-projects `core` and `myModule`.
If you want `myModule` to depend on (and use the output of) `core`, you add a `project` dependency to `myModule`:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':core')
}
```

This will also setup the task dependencies correctly.

Comment: `There is no way around this` - that is what I feared... So I have to find another workaround... thanx

Comment: Okay, please take this sentence with a grain of salt. I'm just speaking from personal experience and don't know the actual Gradle code responsible ;)

Comment: _If you want core to depend on (and use the output of) myModule, you add a project dependency to myModule_ - shouldn't it be inversed?